# GKMatchMakerViewController iMessage invites iOS 10 (beta)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, game-center, ios10

I'm having trouble with GKMatchMakerViewController on iOS 10 beta. I'm using 2 iPhone 5s's to build multiplayer functionality in my project. My issue is this. GKMatchMakerViewController comes up on both phones, but when the button titled "invite friends" is pressed to segue to a message invite one phone works and one phone does not. I have reloaded iOS 10 on the phone that it's not working for, I have made sure that it was connected to iCloud, I have checked my iCloud settings, my privacy settings, notifications settings, messages settings, game center settings, and I can find not difference in how the phones are set up.

My GKMatchmakerViewController was working before I updated to the beta version and according to the WWDC session about gameCenter (link below) and their new API there are no code changes required for GKMatchmakerViewController to work with Messages in iOS 10. So my only guess is that I have something blocking it from pulling up. I have not built in any thinking asking for permission to use the phones messages or contacts, but I didn't have to before and it said no code changes so I didn't spend any time on that.

[Game Center WWDC 2016 link](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/611/)

I'm including a link to my code even though all I do is call GKMatchMakerViewController. Apple's API handles it from there and I only get a protocol when the message is accepted.

[Link to code](https://github.com/bradengray/cardFit)